# How to Reset Python libraries modified by a software on Mac OS X El Capitan to original versions

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, qgis

I am facing problems in python after installing QGIS. While installing QGIS, it mentioned that it would override my `matplotlib` and `numpy` python libraries. I am facing trouble with executing python programs through these overrided libraries. I have tried to uninstall these python libraries using `sudo pip uninstall`. But it says operation not permitted. Maybe QGIS has modified the `sudo` settings for these 2 libraries because I am able to add/delete any other python library. I am okay to uninstall QGIS. Can any one share any ideas whats going wrong and how can I restore my `numpy` and `matplotlib` libraries to the original versions by python from the versions overrided by QGIS?

Comment: did you try this from kyngchaos numpy readme?
Uninstall

Drag the numpy-override folder and numpy-override.pth file from 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

to the Trash.

Run this command in a Terminal:

sudo pkgutil --forget org.scipy.numpy-lion

Comment: Tried. Get this error:
“numpy” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by macOS

Comment: This has happened to a lot of people, including myself. I had to remove the file `numpy-override` inside my python version's `site-packages` folder first and then reinstalled `numpy`. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052734/possible-to-circumvent-numpy-override-pth-for-python#comment83077801_48052734) for some guidance.