# Possible to circumvent numpy-override.pth for python?

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I have been running into issues with numpy, specifically having access to newer functionalities like `numpy.stack` and `numpy.moveaxis` which have been implemented since v1.10.

I have updated `numpy` using `pip`, which is my go-to package manager for python. `pip install --upgrade numpy` returns:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

When I run `pip freeze | grep numpy` I get: `numpy==1.13.3`. However, if I try to run python in Terminal:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.stack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stack'
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.9.2'
>>> numpy.__file__
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override/numpy/__init__.pyc'
```

Clearly python is trying to use an older install specified by `numpy-override.pth`. I think this is was put in place when I installed Quantum GIS (I use kyngchaos installer). I would like to update this version of numpy, but I think that may break dependencies with QGIS. So, I would like to circumvent this and use the updated version of `numpy` as installed by `pip`. However I am under the impression the `numpy-override.pth` overrules all other path settings, and I need a solution that allows QGIS to continue to work.

Any suggestions?

Running Mac OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan.

Comment: I had to remove `numpy-override` and reinstall `numpy` in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `numpy-override.pth`. All it does is tell python where to find `numpy`. And if it's telling python to look in the wrong place then it's not doing its job. By default python will look in `site-packages`. However, the `pth` gets first dibs and can tell python to search somewhere else first. Since `numpy` does indeed exist in the override directory then python is happy to use that version.

**However**, [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202470/reset-python-libraries-modified-by-qgis-on-mac-os-x-to-original-versions/202574) on the GIS stack exchange states that QGIS expects to find numpy in the location that the pth file states (with the override bit).

As such, you may prefer to reinstall numpy with the `--prefix` option and tell `pip` to put `numpy` in the override directory. ie.

```
pip install numpy --target=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override
```